# Short syntax to unwrap kwargs in Python

Tags: python

This looks a bit clumpsy, is there a better way to fetch the values in Python?

```
def contact(*kwargs): 
    firstname   = kwargs.get("firstname", None)       
    lastname    = kwargs.get("lastname", None)
    contact     = kwargs.get("contact", None)
    address     = kwargs.get("address", None)
    email       = kwargs.get("email", None)
    birthdate   = kwargs.get("birthdate", None)
```

Comment: Why do you use variadic keyword arguments (``**kwargs``) instead of explicitly taking each keyword argument? I.e. why don't you use ``def contact(firstname=None, lastname=None, ...):``?

Comment: Just work with the dict. There's no advantage in unpacking the values. And you can get rid of ``, None``, it's already the default fallback when working with ``dict.get(...)``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to create variable from all keyword arguments. But I not really suggest to use this type of solution due to it can make serious turbulence in the development. The `first_name, last_name, email, age` variables are not defined (based on linter). Error message: `Unresolved reference 'last_name'`.

**Code:**

```
def contact(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        globals()[k] = v
    print("first_name={}, last_name={}, email={}, age={}".format(first_name, last_name, email, age))

contact(first_name="Bob", last_name="Joe", email="bob.joe@mail.com", age=40)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
first_name=Bob, last_name=Joe, email=bob.joe@mail.com, age=40
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to add your kwargs to another dictionary using that dictionary's `.update()` method.  For example, this can be used to unpack any keyword arguments into like-named object.attributes, which are stored in the object's `.__dict__`.

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Each given kwarg will be stored as the corresponding object.attribute"""
        self.__dict__.update( kwargs )

c = C( foo = 1, bar = 2)
print(f"These kwargs were unpacked to corresponding c.attributes: {c.foo=}, {c.bar=}")
```

Since `globals()` is also a dict, this also provides a simpler version of the accepted answer by @milanbalazs, though I generally wouldn't recommend polluting your globals (!!) with whatever random kwargs someone might have sent to your function!

```py
def globalizer(**kwargs):
    """For each keyword arg, k = v, sets the global variable k = v."""
    globals().update( kwargs ) 

globalizer( glob = 42 )
print(f"This has changed the global variable {glob=}")
```

It also *sometimes* works to use `locals().update(kwargs)` to unpack kwargs into local variables, depending on context and python implementation, but python docs say you should view `locals()` as read-only, since python implementations often keep track of local variables under the hood using something faster than a dict, and generate a dict mirroring this underlying data only when you demand it with `locals()`, so changing this dict often won't change the actual underlying local variables, unfortunately.  In Python 2, you could work around this by including a call to `exec()` in your function which forced Python 2 to keep track of that function's locals in a real dict, (and you could also use `exec` to dynamically assign locals) but Python 3 has abandoned those bits of flexibility in favor of simpler/faster python implementations and letting you redefine `exec` if you want, so Python 3 sadly doesn't offer much potential for altering dynamically-named locals.

So, in general, I'd usually suggest either keeping kwargs as its own dict, or `.update` some other dict, like an object's `.__dict__` of attributes, to include an "unpacked" version of the kwargs.

Answer (score -2):

if you retrieve the kwargs from the CLI, you could alternatively use a library such as Click: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/